# Suddenly my html started acting weird on an Angular project

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was coding a signUp page when I realized my inputs(checkbox and file) were texts instead of what they were supposed to be. I started undoing things to see what messed it up, and at some point when I deleted a simple input the error went away. I was investigating what in this input could have been causing the problem, but then the error came back without the input. There are no errors in the console or whatsoever.

Has anyone been some similar error?

[image]

area_x fields should be checkbox and the bottom input should be a type=file.

HTML:

```
<ng-form name="FormCadastro" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row ng-cloak">
        <h2>Informação pessoal</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{ 'NAME' | translate }}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control capitalized" ng-disabled="c.nome" ng-model="newUser.nome" name="nome" maxlength="255" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{ 'BIRTH_DATE' | translate }}</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control data-mask" ng-disabled="c.dataNascimento" ng-model="newUser.dataNascimento" name="dataNascimento" required/>
                    <!-- ng-required='!firefox && !safari' -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-hide="c.token">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="newUser.senha" name="senha" minlength="6" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-hide="c.token">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{ 'PASSWORD_CONFIRMATION' | translate }}</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="newUser.confirmaSenha" name="confirmaSenha" minlength="6" match="senha" stopccp required />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{ 'EMAIL' | translate }}</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-disabled="c.email" ng-model="newUser.email" name="email" maxlength="100" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{ 'EMAIL_CONFIRMATION' | translate }}</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-disabled="c.email" ng-model="newUser.confirmaEmail" name="confirmaEmail" maxlength="100" stopccp required />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h2>Endereço</h2>
        <!-- address-line1 input-->
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group ">
                <label>Endereço</label>
                <input class="form-control " id="address-line1 " name="address-line1 " type="text " ng-model="newUser.address1" placeholder="Endereço ">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- address-line2 input-->
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group ">
                <label>Complemento</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control " id="address-line2 " name="address-line2 " ng-model="newUser.address2 " type="text " placeholder="Numero xx ">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- city input-->
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group ">
                <label>Cidade</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control " id="city " ng-model="newUser.city " name="city " type="text " placeholder="Cidade ">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- region input-->
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group ">
                <label>Estado</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control " id="state " ng-model="newUser.state " name="state " type="text " placeholder="Estado ">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- postal-code input-->
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group ">
                <label>CEP</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control " ng-model="newUser.zipCode " id="postal-code " name="postal-code " type="text " placeholder="CEP ">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div ng-if="!isCompany ">
            <h2>Educação</h2>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group ">
                    <label>Escola</label>
                    <input type="text " placeholder="Escola Estadual Profesor ... " class="form-control " ng-model="newUser.school ">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                    <h4>Áreas de interesse</h4>
                    <div class="checkbox ">
                        <label>
                            <input ng-model="newUser.checkbox.value1 " type="checkbox " value="area_1 " checked=" ">Area 1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox ">
                        <label>
                            <input ng-model="newUser.checkbox.value2 " type="checkbox " value="area_2 "> Area 2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox ">
                        <label>
                            <input ng-model="newUser.checkbox.value3 " type="checkbox " value="area_3 "> Area 3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="isCompany ">
            <h2>Quantidade de vagas disponíveis</h2>
            <p class="help-block">Pode ser alterado depois na página de edição</p>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                    <h4>Áreas de interesse</h4>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label>
                            Area 1
                            <input class="form-control " ng-model="newUser.interest_area_1 " type="text " value="0 " checked=" ">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label>
                            Area 2
                            <input class="form-control " ng-model="newUser.interest_area_2 " type="text " value="0 ">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label>
                            Area 3
                            <input class="form-control " ng-model="newUser.interest_area_3 " type="text " value="0 ">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="form-group hidden-overflow ">
                    <label>{{ 'DROP_PICTURES' | translate }}</label>
                    <input type="file " id="fileInput " />
                </div>
                <div class="cropArea ">
                    <img-crop image="newUser.myImage " area-type="square " result-image="newUser.myCroppedImage "></img-crop>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12 ">
                <div ng-controller="modalController ">
                    <div class="help-block " translate="REGISTER-TERMS-MESSAGE " translate-compile></div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit " class="btn btn-success btn-block " ng-click="enviar_primeiro_form() ">{{ 'NEXT' | translate }}</button>
                <p>
                    <div class="spinner " ng-show="loading "></div>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

Comment: We're gonna need some source code. maybe a git repo?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a more concise problem description

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley please don't ask for repo link, problematic code needs to be in the question itself. That is a minimum expectation here

Comment: The HTML: http://pastebin.com/HaR1N60G. Unfortunately I can't provide a small portion of code because I couldn't find what caused the problem. I thought it was a input field, but it`s already removed and the errors continues

Comment: What I generally do here is right click in my IDE and select "compare/local history" and compare the current version against that of a few minutes ago/an hour ago/etc.  Your IDE doesn't do that? No better time to think of a new one than now. Both WebStorm and Eclipse will do that. If you insist on not using one of those, then a daily backup and WinMerge might help. Please don't mis-read my tone here - there's no better time to think about backup than when you just lost your harddrive. Same thing applies here - encounter a problem & solve it NOW. Don't let it bite you twice

Comment: @Mawg I use sublime, so I don't have this option, but I might think about switching after this. Weirdly after I switched from linux to mac my subline won't undo my command-z either :(

Comment: Glad you took my comment in the right spirit. Both WebStorm & Eclipse would be fine, depending on your budget.

Comment: @GiovaniBarcelos can use a version control system like Git, Subversion, Mercurial etc regardless of what IDE you use

Comment: @charlietfl only reason i say repo link is that angular projects can be quite large, so instead of posting every single directive, servicec controller and template that might be involved, I could just take a browse through the repo

Comment: no reason he couldn't provide both. the code he thinks is the problem, and then a link to check the rest

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley most problems can be scaled down into question code. They get closed otherwise

Comment: I agree MOST problems. but this is unusual and angular is notorios for giving hard to read feed back on errors

Comment: @GiovaniBarcelos why do all your attributes have a trailing space in them?

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley I use a plugin called Sublime-HTMLPrettify and it does that. But I don't think this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Really not clear what the specific problem is. Description needs clarification

Comment: @GiovaniBarcelos actually it is

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley indeed it is. Just took them out and it worked. That's very weird since i use this plugin for some time and it never caused me any trouble. Thanks a lot! Post an answer so I can select it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having a space in the input type confuses the browser

```html
<div>
  Working Check Box
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div>
  not a check box
  <input type="checkbox ">
</div>
```

Comment: I use a plugin called Sublime-HTMLPrettify that does it, and it has never caused me any trouble(until now). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think it's the prettify, only some of your code has the attribute issues

Comment: so don't ditch the plugin just yet, until you verify that it is indeed adding the trailing spaces

Comment: @GiovaniBarcelos also be sure to fix your id's as well, im pretty sure those spaces are gonna cause you grief if you try to grab one